# How to combine image and text into one blob in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create my own barcode labels with google apps script.  I'm able to retrieve an image blob of the barcode, but I want to be able to add another row of text to it.  Is it possible to combine or edit the image blob?  If so how would one go about doing that.

Here is my current code for getting the barcode.

```
function createLabel() {
  var url = "http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=20-001-001&style=196&type=C128B&width=200&height=100&xres=1&font=3"
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(image);
}
```

I know the barcode comes with the number of its data below it, but I need to make that number larger and easier to read.

I've tried creating a document and inserting the text and image, but it's just printing like I need it to print.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not offer any image manipulation methods in Apps Script (yet). Maybe when Google Draw supports apps script there will be something you can use to programmatically insert an image into a drawing and add text to it, but for now you will have to create your own ad-hoc solution.

You did not specify what your final goal is - a sheet of same label, a sheet of different labels, or a single label displayed on screen for user to save/download. But here are some ideas to try:

1. Create a 1-page Google Document with a table in it that, when
   printed exactly fits your labels. You will likely have to tinker
   with margins, table and cell dimensions, borders, etc to make it fit
   the labels. This doc will be your template. You script will create a
   copy of this doc, and insert your barcode image(s) and text into the
   table cells. Study [Google Apps Script Drive
   Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/)
   and [Google Apps Script Document
   Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/)
   reference for the methods you can use in your code to do this.
2. If your goal is a single label output to screen for user to
   save/download, explore HTML5 Canvas element and/or Canvas- or
   SVG-manipulating client javascript libraries for drawing your image
   on screen and adding text to it. I have not used these techniques
   much, so can't recommend a definitive resource, but see [this SO
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502308/adding-dynamic-text-on-image)
   for starters. Also check out these js libraries:
   [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS), [HTML Canvas
   Javascript Library](http://html-canvas-lib.sourceforge.net/) and
   [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

Final note: the barcode generator you are using - barcodesinc.com - allows you to generate barcodes without text and/or border. That is probably what you will want for your labels - no point having the code text twice on your label.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've been pontificating on this all weekend.  I think I can accomplish my goal with HtmlService.  Not the image manipulation by the final output. My final out put is for when an item is entered into an inventory system, it will print its barcode.  I've experimented with making a doc already, but you can't adjust the page size enough to print on a label printer.  I will post final outcome.

Comment: Yes, if you are using a special label printer, there is no way to format a google document page to expected size. But those printers usually come with dedicated software which usually allows you to import a list of inventory codes and it would generate and print the labels for you. In this case you just need to store the item code in your inventory system and be able to export a list of those. If your printer uses a long strip of continuous label paper, you could possibly generate a long html page of fixed width with all your barcodes and text using Apps Script and print that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution for my own question. Using the HtmlService I'm able to create the "document" that I need. And print it.  The print ticket and styling of the html needs some fine tuning, but this is going to work.

The "CloudPrintLib" is my connected solution to Google Cloud Print with Apps Script see this blog post for reference.
http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/cloudprint

```
function createLabelDoc() {
  var url = "http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=20-001-001&style=196&type=C128B&width=200&height=100&xres=1&font=3";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setTitle('HtmlAlseLabel');
  html.append('<p>20-001-001</p><br>');
  html.append('<img src="http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=20-001-001&style=196&type=C128B&width=200&height=100&xres=1&font=3"/>')
  //DriveApp.createFile(html.getBlob().setName('HTMLBarcode'));

  var ticket = {
        version: "1.0",
        print: {
          duplex: {
            type: "NO_DUPLEX"
          }
        }
      }


  Logger.log(CloudPrintLib.submit("printeridhere", html.getTitle(), ticket, html.getBlob()));
}
```

Thanks to azawaza for the help thinking through this one.